# King 2 men, but don't kill a man

Tags: checkerboard, board-games

I found mention of this challenge in [a *Science* paper called "Checkers is solved" from 1996](//doi.org/10.1126/science.1144079), but no example was given.

> Beginning at starting position, play moves according to rules of English checkers (8x8 board, men can't capture backwards, king doesn't have larger range than man, captures are forced), such that at least 2 pieces promote, but neither side loses a single piece.

---

I've checked that this is possible, but here are two **bonus questions** that I'd love to know:

1) can more than 2 men get promoted before captures? if so, what's the maximum number? the paper claimed that 6 kings are impossible

2) is this feat possible for other rulesets (Russian, International) as well?

Comment: did you know that there's no "checkers" tag?

Comment: Can you quickly summarize the rules of the other variants (or provide a reference)?

Comment: @BenjaminWang [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkers) has a nice table for the variants, but differences are mostly in the same 3 options - 8x8 or 10x10 board, can man capture backwards, does king have infinite range

Comment: The quote means 2 pieces total to promote or 2 pieces per side?

Comment: I managed to get 1 king. Is there a nice online analysis board for English Checkers? (I've only seen Russian)

Comment: @quarague total

Comment: @BenjaminWang try lidraughts, but I used some random checkers mobile app that had a lot of variants

Comment: Yea exactly, LiDraughts doesn't have English :(